# How to make a callback for my loop function

Tags: javascript, json, callback, jquery-deferred, each

I have a JSON file that keeps URLs. I made a `$.each()` loop to go through the JSON file and then do a SoundCloud function on each iteration of the loop. So in order to get same result of the loop I have to make a callback after each iteration for my SoundCloud function. Here is what I tried:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bLjOHIYsAy?indent=2", function(data){ //Link of the playlist

$.each(data.PlayListArray, function(key, val){ //navigate to array called PlayListArray
     var songLink = val.URL; // the value of URL in the array
}, function(){// Callback Function
    SC.get('/resolve', { url: songLink }, function(track) { 
        $("#demo").append("<p id= "+ track.id + ">" + track.title + "</p>");
    });
 });
});
```

Howevere this callback does not work and does not show the gathered data from SC.get() function of SoundCloud.
Any idea to make it working? Or How can I have deferred method to make a chain of functions ??

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Fq2Rw/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here is passing a 3rd parameter to *each* which is expecting only two. Unless I'm missing something about your exact goal, the code below should work as expected.

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: "b8f06bbb8e4e9e201f9e6e46001c3acb",
});

$.getJSON("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bLjOHIYsAy?indent=2", function(data){ //Link of the playlist
    $.each(data.PlayListArray, function(key, val){ //navigate to array called PlayListArray
        var songLink = val.URL; // the value of URL in the array

        SC.get('/resolve', { url: songLink }, function(track) { 
            $("#demo").append("<p id= "+ track.id + ">" + track.title + "</p>");
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT: I now understand that you want to get the results in the order defined by the data.PlayListArray result set. I think you need to buffer the results and process them only when all answers have been received. The code below is probably not optimal but it may give you some new ideas.

There's is, of course, no way to control in which order the different 'SC.get()' will respond and, consequently, in which order your 'function(track)' callbacks will be called. Waiting for each answer before making the next call -- like your original post is suggesting -- is indeed another possibility, but it will be significantly slower than making all calls in parallel (like the code below does).

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: "b8f06bbb8e4e9e201f9e6e46001c3acb",
});

$.getJSON("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bLjOHIYsAy?indent=2", function(data){ //Link of the playlist
    var answer = {};

    $.each(data.PlayListArray, function(key, val){ //navigate to array called PlayListArray
        var songLink = val.URL; // the value of URL in the array
        SC.get('/resolve', { url: songLink }, function(track) {
            answer[songLink] = track;
            if(Object.keys(answer).length == data.PlayListArray.length) {
                // we've got all results: let's process them by iterating on data.PlayListArray again
                $.each(data.PlayListArray, function(key, val){
                    var track = answer[val.URL];
                    $("#demo").append("<p id= "+ track.id + ">" + track.title + "</p>");
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, but the code you provided is where I started from and where I noticed the loop provide different result each time. [http://jsfiddle.net/Fq2Rw/](http://jsfiddle.net/Fq2Rw/) have look at this and run it copple of times. You will notice that each time the loaded data is in a different orders. Not the same as the are in the array in the JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do async calls in a loop, the rule of thumb is to use a recursive function instead  of a for loop.

```
function loop(i){
    if(i >= data.PlayListArray.length){
        //DONE
    }else{
        SC.get('blabla', function(track){
          //Loop body
          loop(i+1);
        });
     }
}

loop(0);
```

As Arnaulid already pointed out, this sequential execution of callbacks is going to exibit high latency so first be sure that this is what you really want to do.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, `$.getJSON` takes arguments (url, callback), however, you can also chain `.then(callback)`, which is the "promisy" way to do it.

Simplest way to ensure that the displayed list is in the same order as the array from which it is derived, is to append an empty `p` element, then populate it with data when it arrives. You can rely on closure formed by the `$.each` function to keep a reliable reference to the appended `p`.

```
$.getJSON("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bLjOHIYsAy?indent=2").then(function(data) { //Link of the playlist
    var $demo = $("#demo");
    $.each(data.PlayListArray, function(i, item) { //traverse the PlayListArray array
        var $p = $("<p/>").appendTo($demo);//appending an empty <p></p> here ensures the observable playList will be in the same order as data.PlayListArray. 
        SC.get('/resolve', { url: item.URL }, function (track) {
            $p.attr('id', track.id).text(track.title);//flesh out the <p></p> appended above. $p remains available due to closure formed by the outer function.
        });
    });
});
```

Note also that by assigning `$demo` ouside the loop avoids the inefficiency of discovering `$("#demo")` in the DOM on every iteration of the each loop.

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fq2Rw/7/)**